# How to create labels for different values of a categorical variables in Stata?

Tags: stata

I am currently using the followng command to create a bar graph of the mean of climate_science scores by treatment and by a dummy variable (conservative or liberal).

```
graph bar (mean) scale_climate if exclude == 0, over(treatment) xalternate blabel(ba
> r) by(, title(Climate by Treatment & Political Orientation)) by(conservative)
```

How would I put labels on the 0 value to indicate "Liberal" and 1 value to indicate "Conservative" in my graph. [image]

Answer (score 2):

an alternative is:

```
 label define conse 0 "Liberal" 1 "Conservative"
label values conservative conse


graph bar (mean) scale_climate if exclude == 0, over(treatment) xalternate blabel(ba
> r) by(, title(Climate by Treatment & Political Orientation)) by(conservative)
```